# switching from multiple checkout to single checkout in azure devops using typescript

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out in typescript how I will be able to switch from multiple checkout to single checkout in azuredevops

```
this.multipleCheckout = `${tl.getVariable('System.DefaultWorkingDirectory')}/${tl.getVariable('Build.Repository.Name')}/manifests`
```

is existing then the working directory should be `${tl.getVariable('System.DefaultWorkingDirectory')}/${tl.getVariable('Build.Repository.Name')}/

then

```
this.singleCheckout = `${tl.getVariable('System.DefaultWorkingDirectory')}/manifests`
```

is existing then the working directory should be `${tl.getVariable('System.DefaultWorkingDirectory')}/

else this will be undefined, then it should catch if no manifests folder exists.

tried to search over the internet but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Could you please share more details about the issue? I am not sure what problem you meet. Are you looking for the [Azure DevOps predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#build-variables-devops-services)?